# JAVA UDP: Client not receiving reply from server

Tags: java, udp, client-server

These classes succeed to communicate when they are on the same computer. But as soon as we move the "Antenna" to another computer(still on same network) the server still gets the package BUT the client just keeps waiting for a reply.

We have checked som other threads at this site but we still can't find our problem. Anyone who can help?

SERVER RECEIVER CLASS:

```
 package Server;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.DatagramSocket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class RecieverProxy extends Thread {
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private static int length;
    private String reqS;

    public static java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    public static Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(currentTimestamp + "  Server[IP=\""
                    + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
                    + "\"]: Local server is Running...");
            System.out.println(currentTimestamp
                    + "  SERVER: Connecting to MySQL server...");
            DbUpdater.readyDatabase();
            System.out.println(currentTimestamp
                    + "  SERVER: MySQL server is connected!");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.err.println(currentTimestamp + "  SERVER: Ready... waiting...");
        try {
            recieveSendUDP();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * The method will wait for a request, process the request, and then return
     * the reply.
     * 
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public boolean recieveSendUDP() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(6789);

        // modtag forespørgsler
        while (true) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];
                DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length);
                socket.receive(request);
                length = request.getLength();

                String replyS = "ERROR";

                String oldreqS = new String(request.getData());

                if (oldreqS == "[]") {
                    System.out.println(currentTimestamp
                            + "  None bluetooth devices nearby");
                    replyS = "None bluetooth devices nearby";
                } else {
                    String subreqS = oldreqS.substring(0, length);
                    String leftreqS = subreqS.replace("[", "'");
                    String rightreqS = leftreqS.replace("]", "'");
                    reqS = rightreqS.replaceAll(", ", "','");
                    replyS = currentTimestamp
                            + "  SERVER: MAC addresses recieved.";
                }

                // gør svar klar
                int dstPort = request.getPort();
                InetAddress dstAdr = request.getAddress();
                System.out.println(currentTimestamp
                        + "  SERVER: Sending reply to IP: " + dstAdr.toString()
                        + " på port " + dstPort);

                DatagramSocket replySocket = new DatagramSocket();
                replySocket.send(new DatagramPacket(replyS.getBytes(), replyS
                        .getBytes().length, new InetSocketAddress(dstAdr,
                        dstPort)));
                replySocket.close();
                DbUpdater.dbUpdate(reqS);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }
}
```

ANTENNA SENDER CLASS:

```
package Antenna;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Vector;

public class SendRemoteDevices {

    public static java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    public static Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

    public static void runMacSender() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Vector<String> macAdds;

        macAdds = RemoteDeviceDiscovery.getMacVec();
        System.out.println(currentTimestamp
                + "  ANTENNA: Sending macaddresses: " + macAdds);
        sendMacc(macAdds);
    }

    public static void sendMacc(Vector<String> macAdd) {
        String request = new Vector<String>(macAdd).toString().trim();
        String reply = sendReceive(request);
    }

    // send string and receive string
    // her skal serverens addresse stå
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static String sendReceive(String request) {
        String ip = "192.168.10.106";
        String serverIP = ip; // sæt anden IP ind hvis du kører
                                // mellem
                                // to maskiner
        DatagramSocket ds = null;
        byte[] bytes = request.getBytes(); // husk : er seperator

        // sending package after encrypting.
        try {
            ds = new DatagramSocket();
            ds.send(new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length,
                    new InetSocketAddress(serverIP, 6789)));
            System.out.println(currentTimestamp
                    + "  ANTENNA: Send this to serveren: \"" + request + "\"");
            System.out.println(currentTimestamp
                    + "  ANTENNA: Waiting for answer from Server...");
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // gør mig klar til at modtage
        byte[] repBytes = new byte[1000];
        DatagramPacket repGram = new DatagramPacket(repBytes, repBytes.length);
        try {
            ds.receive(repGram);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // receive

        // trim er nødvendigt
        String reply = new String(repGram.getData()).trim();
        System.out.println(currentTimestamp
                + "  ANTENNA: Reply from Server: \"" + reply + "\"");
        try { // fordi den ikke printer ovenstående før menuen
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return reply;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which IP and port is your `ds.receive()` listening on?

Comment: Ok.. I have now tried defining the port in this line:

ds = new DatagramSocket(80);

That made it work once. So that the antenna can send and receive, but only once.

Comment: You can send and receive any number of times.

Comment: Yeah, but it crashed after one successful time (sending and receiving). 

The exception said something about the connection already being binded and referring to the line with: ds = new DatagramSocket(80); 

After playing around with it, i unfortunately can't replicate the exception. No matter what i do now the antenna is just waiting for a reply.